# Ovirt Hosted-Engine Deleted

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, kvm, ovirt

Dear lovely stackoverflow community,

Yesterday I accidentally deleted my ovirt-engine-domain.

--> surprisingly the whole folder is gone, and its **not restoreable**

Of course my VMs are still running, but I don't have any backup of my **self-hosted-engine**. :(

I have decided to install a new engine this weekend. I would appreciate any recommendations.

My Plan: reinstall everything :(

Im Using **CentOS 7.3** and was using **Ovirt 4.1**

---

Is there a possibility to re-install a new Hosted-Engine without a fresh OS?

Is there a possibility to clean a Ovirt-Node so I can use it in another Engine-environment?

Does anybody have any experiences with this:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_virtualization/4.1/html/self-hosted_engine_guide/cleaning_up_a_failed_self-hosted_engine_deployment

> ovirt-hosted-engine-cleanup?
>
> ovirt-hosted-engine-deploy answerfile?

---

Comment: This should be on Serverfault